# Bounded Function that is Continuous Except at Sequence Converging to $0$ is Riemann Integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Studying for a qualifying exam. This problem is from an old exam, not quite sure how to set this up. I am to adhere only to the definition of Riemann integrability, no measure theory.

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence converging to $0$. Suppose $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded, and $f$ is continuous except on the set $\{x \in [0,1]\ |\ x = a_n\ \text{for some}\ n\}$. Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

Thoughts are that I should partition $[0,1]$ up along the points of discontinuity. However, this is a countable set, which is an issue for the partition. My other idea is when I fix an epsilon, I get an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_n| < \epsilon\ $ for $\ n \geq N$. Using this, I can 'clump" the tail of the seuqence into one partition, and then partition the rest of the interval $[0,1]$ along the points of discontinuity. But then I have discontinuities inside of the first partition, not sure if that matters? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show that the upper and lower Riemann sums can be made arbitrarily close?

Comment: I mean, if I could, I wouldn't have asked the question, as that is the definition of being Riemann integrable. I suppose my difficulty is in selecting the partition to compute the upper and lower sums. Not sure how to handle the discontinuities.

Comment: Do you have any control on the value that $f$ takes on the sequence of $a_n$? That is, do you know if $f(a_n)$ as to take some particular value?

Comment: Partition the interval as $[0,\epsilon], [\epsilon, 1]$. The number of discontinuities of $f$ on $[\epsilon, 1]$ is finite (why?) so it is integrable there and the difference between Darboux sums can be made less than $\epsilon$. Something similar can be done for $[0,\epsilon] $ because the interval itself is of small size and function is bounded.

Comment: More generally you can show that if $f$ is bounded and the set $D$ (of discontinuities of $f$) has a finite number of accumulation points then $f$ is Riemann integrable. Idea of the proof remains same as in last comment.

Comment: One can also use the fact that discontinuities form a countable set and hence the function is integrable, but the proof is a bit complicated.

Comment: I appreciate the comments! I was able to come up with a solution. I'll write it up, and post it later.